# FTP directory listing fails in Cyberduck and FileZilla, but works on commandline

Tags: macos, ftp, filezilla, cyberduck

I'm trying to connect to an FTP server (running FileZilla 0.9.56b on Windows 7) using my Mac (running OS X 10.10). The server is directly connected to the Internet and configured to let the passive mode ports through at the Windows firewall, as per the FileZilla Server documentation.

I've tried to connect with Cyberduck Version 4.8.3 (19083) and FileZilla 3.16.0, and the connection itself works, but the directory listing always fails.

The interesting part is that through the command-line `ftp` client, it works:

```
  % ftp user@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx                                                                                                                             !4861
Connected to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.
220-FileZilla Server 0.9.56 beta
220-written by Tim Kosse (tim.kosse@filezilla-project.org)
220 Please visit https://filezilla-project.org/
331 Password required for user
Password:
230 Logged on
Remote system type is UNIX.
ftp> ls
229 Entering Extended Passive Mode (|||50076|)
150 Opening data channel for directory listing of "/"
-rw-r--r-- 1 ftp ftp           6148 Jan 21  2016 .DS_Store
drwxr-xr-x 1 ftp ftp              0 Feb 22 16:52 Data
226 Successfully transferred "/"
```

On FileZilla, I get this:

```
Status:         Disconnected from server
Status:         Connecting to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:21...
Status:         Connection established, waiting for welcome message...
Status:         Initializing TLS...
Status:         Verifying certificate...
Status:         TLS connection established.
Status:         Logged in
Status:         Retrieving directory listing...
Command:    PWD
Response:   257 "/" is current directory.
Command:    TYPE I
Response:   200 Type set to I
Command:    PASV
Response:   227 Entering Passive Mode (xxx,xxx,xxx,xxx,195,141)
Command:    MLSD
Response:   425 Can't open data connection for transfer of "/"
Error:          Failed to retrieve directory listing
```

And it waits a while until it says "Directory listing failed". It's similar on Cyberduck.

What could be the problem here? The [Online FTP tester](https://ftptest.net/) also reports my server as working.

Here are the server logs from the failed connection:

```
(000004)3/11/2016 16:43:42 PM - (not logged in) (141.241.26.7)> Connected on port 21, sending welcome message...
(000004)3/11/2016 16:43:42 PM - (not logged in) (141.241.26.7)> 220-FileZilla Server 0.9.56 beta
(000004)3/11/2016 16:43:42 PM - (not logged in) (141.241.26.7)> 220-written by Tim Kosse (tim.kosse@filezilla-project.org)
(000004)3/11/2016 16:43:42 PM - (not logged in) (141.241.26.7)> 220 Please visit https://filezilla-project.org/
(000004)3/11/2016 16:43:42 PM - (not logged in) (141.241.26.7)> AUTH TLS
(000004)3/11/2016 16:43:42 PM - (not logged in) (141.241.26.7)> 234 Using authentication type TLS
(000004)3/11/2016 16:43:42 PM - (not logged in) (141.241.26.7)> SSL connection established
(000004)3/11/2016 16:43:44 PM - (not logged in) (141.241.26.7)> USER user
(000004)3/11/2016 16:43:44 PM - (not logged in) (141.241.26.7)> 331 Password required for user
(000004)3/11/2016 16:43:44 PM - (not logged in) (141.241.26.7)> PASS *********
(000004)3/11/2016 16:43:44 PM - user (141.241.26.7)> 230 Logged on
(000004)3/11/2016 16:43:44 PM - user (141.241.26.7)> SYST
(000004)3/11/2016 16:43:44 PM - user (141.241.26.7)> 215 UNIX emulated by FileZilla
(000004)3/11/2016 16:43:44 PM - user (141.241.26.7)> FEAT
(000004)3/11/2016 16:43:44 PM - user (141.241.26.7)> 211-Features:
(000004)3/11/2016 16:43:44 PM - user (141.241.26.7)>  MDTM
(000004)3/11/2016 16:43:44 PM - user (141.241.26.7)>  REST STREAM
(000004)3/11/2016 16:43:44 PM - user (141.241.26.7)>  SIZE
(000004)3/11/2016 16:43:44 PM - user (141.241.26.7)>  MLST type*;size*;modify*;
(000004)3/11/2016 16:43:44 PM - user (141.241.26.7)>  MLSD
(000004)3/11/2016 16:43:44 PM - user (141.241.26.7)>  AUTH SSL
(000004)3/11/2016 16:43:44 PM - user (141.241.26.7)>  AUTH TLS
(000004)3/11/2016 16:43:44 PM - user (141.241.26.7)>  PROT
(000004)3/11/2016 16:43:44 PM - user (141.241.26.7)>  PBSZ
(000004)3/11/2016 16:43:44 PM - user (141.241.26.7)>  UTF8
(000004)3/11/2016 16:43:44 PM - user (141.241.26.7)>  CLNT
(000004)3/11/2016 16:43:44 PM - user (141.241.26.7)>  MFMT
(000004)3/11/2016 16:43:44 PM - user (141.241.26.7)>  EPSV
(000004)3/11/2016 16:43:44 PM - user (141.241.26.7)>  EPRT
(000004)3/11/2016 16:43:44 PM - user (141.241.26.7)> 211 End
(000004)3/11/2016 16:43:44 PM - user (141.241.26.7)> PBSZ 0
(000004)3/11/2016 16:43:44 PM - user (141.241.26.7)> 200 PBSZ=0
(000004)3/11/2016 16:43:44 PM - user (141.241.26.7)> PROT P
(000004)3/11/2016 16:43:44 PM - user (141.241.26.7)> 200 Protection level set to P
(000004)3/11/2016 16:43:44 PM - user (141.241.26.7)> PWD
(000004)3/11/2016 16:43:44 PM - user (141.241.26.7)> 257 "/" is current directory.
(000004)3/11/2016 16:43:44 PM - user (141.241.26.7)> TYPE I
(000004)3/11/2016 16:43:44 PM - user (141.241.26.7)> 200 Type set to I
(000004)3/11/2016 16:43:44 PM - user (141.241.26.7)> PASV
(000004)3/11/2016 16:43:44 PM - user (141.241.26.7)> 227 Entering Passive Mode (xxx,xxx,xxx,xxx,199,23)
(000004)3/11/2016 16:43:44 PM - user (141.241.26.7)> MLSD
(000004)3/11/2016 16:43:54 PM - user (141.241.26.7)> 425 Can't open data connection for transfer of "/"
```

Here's the working one:

```
(000005)3/11/2016 16:46:55 PM - (not logged in) (141.241.26.7)> Connected on port 21, sending welcome message...
(000005)3/11/2016 16:46:55 PM - (not logged in) (141.241.26.7)> 220-FileZilla Server 0.9.56 beta
(000005)3/11/2016 16:46:55 PM - (not logged in) (141.241.26.7)> 220-written by Tim Kosse (tim.kosse@filezilla-project.org)
(000005)3/11/2016 16:46:55 PM - (not logged in) (141.241.26.7)> 220 Please visit https://filezilla-project.org/
(000005)3/11/2016 16:46:55 PM - (not logged in) (141.241.26.7)> USER user
(000005)3/11/2016 16:46:55 PM - (not logged in) (141.241.26.7)> 331 Password required for user
(000005)3/11/2016 16:47:01 PM - (not logged in) (141.241.26.7)> PASS *********
(000005)3/11/2016 16:47:01 PM - user (141.241.26.7)> 230 Logged on
(000005)3/11/2016 16:47:01 PM - user (141.241.26.7)> SYST
(000005)3/11/2016 16:47:01 PM - user (141.241.26.7)> 215 UNIX emulated by FileZilla
(000005)3/11/2016 16:47:01 PM - user (141.241.26.7)> FEAT
(000005)3/11/2016 16:47:01 PM - user (141.241.26.7)> 211-Features:
(000005)3/11/2016 16:47:01 PM - user (141.241.26.7)>  MDTM
(000005)3/11/2016 16:47:01 PM - user (141.241.26.7)>  REST STREAM
(000005)3/11/2016 16:47:01 PM - user (141.241.26.7)>  SIZE
(000005)3/11/2016 16:47:01 PM - user (141.241.26.7)>  MLST type*;size*;modify*;
(000005)3/11/2016 16:47:01 PM - user (141.241.26.7)>  MLSD
(000005)3/11/2016 16:47:01 PM - user (141.241.26.7)>  AUTH SSL
(000005)3/11/2016 16:47:01 PM - user (141.241.26.7)>  AUTH TLS
(000005)3/11/2016 16:47:01 PM - user (141.241.26.7)>  PROT
(000005)3/11/2016 16:47:01 PM - user (141.241.26.7)>  PBSZ
(000005)3/11/2016 16:47:01 PM - user (141.241.26.7)>  UTF8
(000005)3/11/2016 16:47:01 PM - user (141.241.26.7)>  CLNT
(000005)3/11/2016 16:47:01 PM - user (141.241.26.7)>  MFMT
(000005)3/11/2016 16:47:01 PM - user (141.241.26.7)>  EPSV
(000005)3/11/2016 16:47:01 PM - user (141.241.26.7)>  EPRT
(000005)3/11/2016 16:47:01 PM - user (141.241.26.7)> 211 End
(000005)3/11/2016 16:47:01 PM - user (141.241.26.7)> PWD
(000005)3/11/2016 16:47:01 PM - user (141.241.26.7)> 257 "/" is current directory.
(000005)3/11/2016 16:47:02 PM - user (141.241.26.7)> EPSV
(000005)3/11/2016 16:47:02 PM - user (141.241.26.7)> 229 Entering Extended Passive Mode (|||50629|)
(000005)3/11/2016 16:47:02 PM - user (141.241.26.7)> LIST
(000005)3/11/2016 16:47:02 PM - user (141.241.26.7)> 150 Opening data channel for directory listing of "/"
(000005)3/11/2016 16:47:02 PM - user (141.241.26.7)> 226 Successfully transferred "/"
```

Comment: Are the IP addresses in the `Connecting to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:21...` and `227 Entering Passive Mode (xxx,xxx,xxx,xxx,195,141)` the same?

Comment: Did you try to turn off the TLS? That's what's different to the command-line.

Comment: Huh, yeah, this works. Didn't see that the commandline didn't use it. Any idea why TLS wouldn't work here?

Comment: No, though again, can you show us both client- and server- side logs for the initial FileZilla client attempt? The logs you have appended are for retry with fallback to legacy `PASV`.

Comment: But they always fall back to PASV. I'll come back to you next week, now heading to a weekend without Internet.

Comment: I know the FileZilla falls back always, I just wonder if the original failure (that causes the fallback) is the same.